# SQL Server and MS Access database active on the same host computer

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

Is it possible to have both active on the same computer and available to users?
I'm asking because I have to make a c# application using SQL Server but my client only has one available computer to host the SQL Server and that machine already has a MS Access database running on it.

Thanks

Comment: Yes. They use completely different resources.

Comment: I think, I would have to configure one on a different port. Since they both use 1433, right?

Comment: I have no idea what port MS-Access would use. My guess is that it's just using the network file system, so that it's not using tcp port 1433. If it is typing up port 1433, it's a simple matter to reconfigure SQL Server to use a different port.

Comment: @Ecnerwal Access is a file based database and has no process running and doesn't bind to any port at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Access utilizes a file-based database system, it has no server components running, unlike SQL Server.  You can certainly utilize both on the same machine.

Comment: Would you mind to explain a little bit more about how access works? Id be really grateful

Comment: I think others have provided good explanations of the differences:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5704654/sql-server-express-vs-ms-access