# Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 provider is not registered on the hosting machine

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

i have installed 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' in my local machine. its working properly. but , when i host website i got this error. what i do??

i have registered in webconfig

```
<add name ="Excel03ConString"

    connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};

                     Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR={1}'" providerName="Microsoft.Office.Interop"/>

<add name ="Excel07ConString"

     connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};

                     Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR={1}'" providerName="Microsoft.Office.Interop"/>
```

Comment: Did you get any answer that solved your problem ??

Answer (score 0):

Try the following steps to make sure MDAC features run properly in target machine:

1) Make sure you're using correct provider name in OLE DB connection string, i.e. `System.Data.OleDb` like example below.

```
<add name ="Excel03ConString" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\example.mdb;Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes'" providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />

<add name ="Excel07ConString" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\example.accdb;Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes'" providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />
```

Note that `Microsoft.Office.Interop` may work locally because the development machine has Office interop installed, but in hosting machine will not work if the interop doesn't exist or not installed.

2) Change solution platform from "Any CPU" to "x86" in project settings.

3) Set "**Enable 32-bit Applications**" value to "True" on IIS Manager if you have access to manage IIS.

4) Install MDAC driver which corresponds to current hosting machine platform (x86 or x64) if you have required privileges to install MDAC driver in hosting machine.

**Side note:** If you want to use the application in multi-user environment, SQL Server is better suited than Access database because [SQL Server uses client-server model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5704654/sql-server-express-vs-ms-access).

Similar issue:

[The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11179905/the-microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine/12754336)

Comment: again i got same Error.

Comment: Did you try all given possible solutions already? The message tells you that the host has OLE DB provider issue, either by incorrect provider name or mismatched plaform selection.

Answer (score 0):

Download and install Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 and 2007 Redistributable to solve "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 provider is not registered on the hosting machine" error.